# If radio is clicked active input and get value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 3 radio inputs and 1 text input. Text input is disabled by "disabled" attribute. What I want to do is when I click on third radio input my text input should be active. When I click on another radio input my text input should be disabled again. Next I want to pass values to span element. So, when I click on first radio my span should have this value etc. I don't know how to get value from my text input when it's enabled.

```js
    $('#sause-oth').on('click', function(){
            $("#sause-other").prop("disabled", false);
    });
    $('.radio').on('click', function(){
        $("#sause-other").prop("disabled", true);
    });

    $('input[name="sause"]').on('change', function(){
        $('#summary_sause').html($(this).val());
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
    <label for="sause-light">Sos ladgodny</label> <br>
    <input type="radio" name="sause" id="sause-light" value="sos lagodny" class="radio"> <br>
    <label for="sause-hot">Sos ostry</label> <br>
    <input type="radio" name="sause" id="sause-hot" value="sos ostry" class="radio"> <br>
    <label for="sause-other">Sos inny</label> <br>
    <input type="radio" name="sause" id="sause-oth" class="enable">
    <input type="text" name="sause-other" id="sause-other" disabled="disabled">
</section>

<hr>

<p>Sos: <span id="summary_sause"></span></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```js
$(function(){
  $('[name=sause]').on('change', function() {
    if( $(this).attr('id') == 'sause-oth' ) {
      $("#sause-other").prop("disabled", false);
    }
    else {
      $("#sause-other").prop("disabled", true).val('');
      $('#summary_sause').html($(this).val());
    }
  });
  /* changes the text when focus is out of the field */
  $('#sause-other').on('change', function() {
    $('#summary_sause').html($(this).val());
  });
  /* changes the text on key release */
  /*
  $('#sause-other').on('keyup', function() {
    $('#summary_sause').html($(this).val());
  });
  */
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <label for="sause-light">Sos ladgodny</label> <br>
  <input type="radio" name="sause" id="sause-light" value="sos lagodny" class="radio"> <br>
  <label for="sause-hot">Sos ostry</label> <br>
  <input type="radio" name="sause" id="sause-hot" value="sos ostry" class="radio"> <br>
  <label for="sause-other">Sos inny</label> <br>
  <input type="radio" name="sause" id="sause-oth" class="enable">
  <input type="text" name="sause-other" id="sause-other" disabled="disabled">
</section>

<hr>

<p>Sos: <span id="summary_sause"></span></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the value from text on put it on span

```
$( "#sause-other" ).keyup(function() {
      var text = $(this).val();
      $( "#summary_sause" ).html( text );
});
```

You can summarize your existing code:

```
 $('input[name="sause"]').on('change', function() {
     var value = $(this).val();

     if (value == "on") {
       $("#sause-other").prop("disabled", false);
       $("#summary_sause").html("");
     } else {
       $("#sause-other").prop("disabled", true);
       $("#summary_sause").html(value);
     }
   });
```

Link:
https://jsfiddle.net/832wnhpt/1/

Answer (score 0):

Update your code like this to make it change

```js
$('#sause-oth').on('click', function(){
            $("#sause-other").prop("disabled", false);
    });
    $('.radio').on('click', function(){
        $("#sause-other").prop("disabled", true);
    });

    $('input[name="sause"]').on('change', function(){
        add($(this).val());
    });
    
    function add(value){
      $('#summary_sause').html(value);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
    <label for="sause-light">Sos ladgodny</label> <br>
    <input type="radio" name="sause" id="sause-light" value="sos lagodny" class="radio"> <br>
    <label for="sause-hot">Sos ostry</label> <br>
    <input type="radio" name="sause" id="sause-hot" value="sos ostry" class="radio"> <br>
    <label for="sause-other">Sos inny</label> <br>
    <input type="radio" name="sause" id="sause-oth" class="enable" value="">
    <input onkeyup="add(this.value)" type="text" name="sause-other" id="sause-other" disabled="disabled">
</section>

<hr>

<p>Sos: <span id="summary_sause"></span></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I correctly understood what you want but I guess you need something like this:

```js
$('#sause-oth').on('click', function() {
  $("#sause-other").prop("disabled", false);
});

$('.radio').on('click', function() {
  $("#sause-other").prop("disabled", true);
});

$('#sause-other').on('keyup', function() {
  $('#summary_sause').html($(this).val());
});

$('input[name="sause"]').on('change', function() {
  var val = this.id === 'sause-oth' ? $('#sause-other').val() : $(this).val();
  $('#summary_sause').html(val);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <label for="sause-light">Sos ladgodny</label> <br>
  <input type="radio" name="sause" id="sause-light" value="sos lagodny" class="radio"> <br>
  <label for="sause-hot">Sos ostry</label> <br>
  <input type="radio" name="sause" id="sause-hot" value="sos ostry" class="radio"> <br>
  <label for="sause-other">Sos inny</label> <br>
  <input type="radio" name="sause" id="sause-oth" class="enable">
  <input type="text" name="sause-other" id="sause-other" disabled="disabled">
</section>

<hr>

<p>Sos: <span id="summary_sause"></span></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answer as far as I saw didn't cover the case when you choose another button then come back to the text. Try this.

```js
    $('#sause-oth').on('click', function(){
            $("#sause-other").prop("disabled", false);
    });
    $('.radio').on('click', function(){
        $("#sause-other").prop("disabled", true);
    });

    $('input[name="sause"]').on('change', function(){
        $('#summary_sause').html($(this).val());
    });

    $( "#sause-other" ).on('input', function() {
        $('#summary_sause').html($(this).val());
        $("#sause-oth").val($(this).val());
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
    <label for="sause-light">Sos ladgodny</label> <br>
    <input type="radio" name="sause" id="sause-light" value="sos lagodny" class="radio"> <br>
    <label for="sause-hot">Sos ostry</label> <br>
    <input type="radio" name="sause" id="sause-hot" value="sos ostry" class="radio"> <br>
    <label for="sause-other">Sos inny</label> <br>
    <input type="radio" name="sause" id="sause-oth" class="enable">
    <input type="text" name="sause-other" id="sause-other" disabled="disabled">
</section>

<hr>

<p>Sos: <span id="summary_sause"></span></p>
```